# Adjusting regression weight based on feedback

Tags: r, regression

Let's say I want to predict a dependent variable `D`, where:

```
D<-rnorm(100)
```

I cannot observe D, but I know the values of three predictor variables:

```
I1<-D+rnorm(100,0,10)
I2<-D+rnorm(100,0,30)
I3<-D+rnorm(100,0,50)
```

I want to predict D by using the following regression equation:

```
I1 * w1 + I2 * w2 + I3 * w3 = ~D
```

however, I do not know the correct values of the weights (`w`), but I would like to fine-tune them by repeating my estimate:

1. in the first step I use equal weights:

   `w1= .33`, `w2=.33`, `w3=.33`

and I estimate `D` using these weights:

```
EST= I1 * .33 + I2 * .33 + I3 *. 33
```

1. I receive feedback, which is a difference score between `D` and my estimate (`diff=D-EST`)
2. I use this feedback to modify my original weights and fine-tune them to eventually minimize the difference between `D` and `EST`.

My question is:

1. Is the difference score sufficient for being able to fine-tune the weights?
2. What are some ways of manually fine-tuning the weights? (e.g. can I look at the correlation between `diff` and `I1,I2,I3` and use that as a weight?

Comment: This is not really a coding question but rather a methodology question. It's more suited to CrossValidated.com

Comment: I agree with @Dwin, this is more a methodological question. Also, is your example just a simplification of your actual problem or do you really know that your instruments `I1`, `I2`, and `I3` are just `D` plus some i.i.d. noise? In that case, it should be fairly straightforward to extract the latent process `D`, my first guess would be a factor analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command,

```
coefficients(lm(D ~ I1 + I2 + I3))
```

will give you the ideal weights to minimize `diff`.

Your defined `diff` will not tell you enough to manually manipulate the weights correctly as there is no way to isolate the error component of each `I`.

The correlation between `D` and the `I`'s is not sufficient either as it only tells you the strength of the predictor, not the weight. If your `I`'s are truly independent (both from each other, all together and w.r.t. `D` - a strong assumption, but true when using `rnorm` for each), you could try manipulating one at a time and notice how it affects `diff`, but using a linear regression model is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: and what if I keep the weights at .33 and want to adjust the I's? Can I use the correlation between I and D to change the values of I?

Comment: When you say change the I's do you mean change the parameters in the `rnorm` function used to generate them?

Comment: No just simply say that instead of using 3 predictors I use 1 predictor which gets rid of the independence problem. and then I just use one predictor and try to adjust its weight to get closer to D.

Comment: If you just had one predictor, it would be pretty easy to manually adjust its weight. Again, `coefficients(lm(D ~ I))` would get you the exact closest weight, but you could certainly increase and decrease the weight manually and see immediately from `diff` if you were moving in the right or wrong direction.

Comment: right but D is not observable, so lm is not an option. So should I just simply substract 0.1 to the weight if the diff is getting larger and add 0.1 if its getting smaller?

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I completely missed that D was not observable. Yep, pretty much, if the error is getting worse, you're moving in the wrong direction.